# In what order does OpenGL draws edges?

Tags: opengl

The following code is the code that draws a pyramid on the three dimensional space, my question is how exactly OpenGL draws the edges of the pyramid? And in what order?

I know that in the two dimensional space we start drawing from lower left vertex and right against the direction of the clock.

My pyramid code:

```
glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(0,-1,1);
  glColor3f (1.0, 1.5,0.0);
  glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,1); 
    glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,-1);
    glVertex3f(0,0,0.5);
    glVertex3f(-1,-1,1);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,1); 
    glVertex3f(0,0,0.5);
    glVertex3f(1,-1,-1);
  glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: I haven't worked with openGL for a while. But I think the order depends on your glVertex method order.
I'd use triangles to do it but that's just me...

Comment: What difference it makes to you if OpenGL draws the lines in some other order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `GL_LINE_LOOP` drawing mode OpenGL draws a line from `0` vertex to `1`, then from `1` to `2`, `2` to `3` and so on... At the end it closes the `loop` with a line from the last vertex to the `0th` one. This is why it's called a `line loop`.

EDIT:

What you say about direction in 2D space - it really doesn't matter if you draw lines or a line loop. The direction `against the clock` is mostly used for drawing triangles, to distinguish front-faced and back-faced ones. Using this you can easily clip many not visible triangles.